# Grouping by type and subtype

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three columns one is Type and other is subtype and the third is variety. I was trying to group by Type and find out how many unique subtype belongs to the certain type.

For Example Type is fruit and subtype is banana, apple , orange.

| Type | subtype | Variety |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | banana | A |
| fruit | banana | B |
| fruit | banana | C |
| fruit | apple | A |
| fruit | apple | B |
| fruit | apple | C |

Desired Result:

| type | subtype |
| --- | --- |
| fruit | banana |
| fruit | apple |
| fruit | orange |

The total no. of rows are 700 and consists of 30 different types.

Comment: `df.groupby(['fruit']).agg({'subtype':'nunique'})` You'll have to select just the type and subtype columns with `df = df[['type','subtype']]`. `.agg` with the `nunique` argument counts the number of unique data points in the column you're `agg`'ing for each `fruit` grouping.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood, are you trying to figure out the number of unique varieties for each type/subtype combo?

Comment: Yep worked fine I used 'unique' instead of 'nunique' as i wanted the names. This will help me decide which column to keep for the modelling part. Thanks!

Comment: Where does 'orange' come from as it does not appear in your initial table?

Comment: Orange came as I wrote that there are more than 700 rows with 30 different types so one of the subtype is orange as well. This was an example case I cannot post the actual thing as it is business related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
result = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Type', 'subtype']).drop('Variety', 1)
```

Comment: If I have a place column as well to see where does it come from. Can I use the same code to see in same row where it comes from without duplicates. I tried it without dropping the third row, It worked wonderfully

Comment: It'll keep the 1st info and drop the other. Can you add the complete question?. It may require a different solution.

Comment: Example fruit Banana A is coming from USA fruit apple A is also coming from USA fruit apple B is coming from Netherland and so on so I wanted to group each uniques with each other but I tried the same code you provided and It worked for me. I used

    `result = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Type', 'subtype'])`

Comment: There is another question I have a situation which I never worked on before on same dataset I put on the question fairly poorly at first and now It wont get answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67575127/15077161
If anyone can have a look
Merge wont work there and other already present solution