# merging dataset based values of another data set

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe the data in first is like:

| Name | Company | Model | Year | KmDriven | Variant | Engine | FuelType | Safety | AgentResponsible |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car1 | Honda | HondaCity | 2006 | 10000 | V | V6 | Diesel | 4 |  |
| car2 | Huandai | Santro | 2008 | 20000 | XL | V10 | Petrol | 3 |  |
| car3 | Tata | Altroz | 2019 | 5000 | X | V6 | Diesel | 5 |  |
| car4 | Ford | Figo | 2018 | 10000 | M | V6 | Petrol | 4 |  |
| car5 | Tata | Nexon | 2020 | 5000 | XL | V10 | Diesel | 4 |  |

The second dataset is:

| Company | Engine | FuelType | Safety | AgentResponsible |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Honda | V6 | Diesel | 3 | Vinod |
| Honda | V10 | Diesel | 3 | Vinod |
| Honda | V6 | Diesel | 4 | Akash |
| Honda | V6 | Diesel | 5 | Akash |
| Tata | V6 | Diesel | 4 | Amit |
| Tata | V10 | Petrol | 5 | Akash |
| Tata | V10 | Diesel | 4 | Amit |
| Huandai | V10 | Petrol | 3 | Silva |
| Huandai | V10 | Diesel | 4 | Silva |
| Huandai | V10 | Diesel | 5 | Silva |
| Ford | V10 | Diesel | 4 | Silva |
| Ford | V6 | Petrol | 4 | Amit |

Based on the second dataset I want to fill the Agent Responsible in the First data set. Both dataset are of different dimensions of rows and columns.

The D1 in actual is 1900x20 and D2 is 395x5.

The dataset 2 have around 320 combinations of the 4 columns to provide a name but same person can represent more than 1 combination as shown in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df1 = (
    df1.merge(
        df2,
        left_on=['Company', 'Engine', 'FuelType', 'Safety'],
        right_on=['Company', 'Engine', 'FuelType', 'Safety'],
        how='left')
    .drop('AgentResponsible_x', 1)
    .rename(columns={'AgentResponsible_y': 'AgentResponsible'})
)
```

Comment: Since the df1 and df2 are not similar based on index and I am pretty sure that all the 300 combinations will be repeated in those of df1 in those 1900 rows so will this code raise Nan values or it will keep checking on loop throughout the df1 and fill all the values. for example car50 is similar to that of car 1 and name Akash should assign but df2 has already ran out of index.

Comment: It worked and made me realize I need to go back to concepts again. Thank you !